# git: unstaging changes on merge without effecting future merge

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a project that splits into few branches(each branch is for a different website).
I want to merge some changes from master to other branches but not all of them.
I did it with a branch by unstaging the changes before committing the merge.
The problem is when I'm trying to merge a new change from the master, it shows the unstaged files on the pull request.
Is there any way of unstaging files on merge with git "thinking" the branch is exactly like master and getting only new commits on the next merge?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

not a full answer, but the command you're looking for is `cherry-pick`. You can Google it, many answers on SO already.